# Create lists based on condition in another lists

Tags: python, list, algorithm, loops, tuples

I have lists below:

```
    I = [1, 2, 3]
    U = [4, 5, 6]
    N = [7, 8, 9]
```

I want to get the following:

```
    for each number in list N I want to get the group of lists like that:
    for N[0] = 7  > P = [I[0], U[0], 0] = [1, 4, 0, 0, 0, 0]
    for N[1] = 8 > P = [I[0], I[1], U[0], U[1], 0, 0] = [1, 2, 4, 5, 0, 0]
    for N[2] = 9 > P = [I[0], I[1], I[2], U[0], U[1], U[2]] = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6]
```

The idea is that for the first element in list N I want to get the list P that will have the first element from lists I and U and the rest will be zero (the length should be always be the same and equals to len(I) + len(U). In my example, for demonstration purposes, the length on list N equals to 3 but in reality it can be 1000 and more. So I need an algorithm that will iterate through list N and create new lists based on values and positions in lists I and U. It may sound awkward and please ask if you need clarifications.

Comment: What is the content of list N used for?

Comment: It is for machine learning purposes where N is my target and list P is my features that corresponds to my target value.

Comment: Got it. What I meant to say is, does the content in list N matter or are you just counting?

Comment: For N[n], the list P includes all values before i.e. P = [I[0], I[1],...,I[n], U[0], U[1],..., U[n]]

Comment: Ah, okay. This is possible, but tricky. Give me a minute.

Comment: Of course it matters, all numbers in my discription are just illustration what I want to get. In my specific case, length of N is 2000. So basically I have to get 2000 different lists for each value of N. Is that clear?

Comment: Where exactly did you get stuck?

Comment: At the very beggining, how can I iteratively add values based from two lists I and U to new list P based on index of list N?

Comment: I've managed to get output that looks like this: `[4, 7, 4, 5, 7, 8]`. Is that correct?

Comment: Nope, you should get 1 output for each value of list N as in example above.

Comment: Basically, if len(N) = 3 then you have to get  3 lists.

Comment: Could you show what the output should look like so that I can fix the issue?

Comment: Output should be a list of lists like that: P = [[1, 4, 0, 0, 0, 0], [1, 2, 4, 5, 0, 0], [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6]]

Comment: One last question: Will there only ever be two lists (U and N)?

Comment: The algorithm should be flexible in my point of view. Maybe later I will extend the features. But for now it can be two lists only if it is easier. Ask as many questions as you need.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/230272/discussion-between-blue-and-roman-lents).

Comment: What are you using this code for? It sounds interesting.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The final code is as follows:

```
i = [1, 2, 3]
u = [4, 5, 6]
n = [7, 8, 9]
l = [i, u] # This works with any number of lists :)
p = []
#Get the total length of all the lists in l
total = 0
for item in l:
  total += len(item)

for y in range(0, len(n) + 1):
  _p = []
  for item in l:
   for x in range(0, y):
    _p.append(item[x])
  for item in range(0, total - len(_p)):
    _p.append(0)
  p.append(_p)
p.pop(0) #Removes mystery empty element

print(p)
```